# MVC 4 URL rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-4

I don't find how I can create a "fake" subfolder in MVC4.

I want that an URL like

```
AREA/CONTROLLERNAME/FAKEFOLDER/ACTION/
```

goes to

```
AREA/CONTROLLERNAME/ACTION
```

Is it possibile? Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using routing? For example assuming you have an `Admin` area:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/FAKEFOLDER/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Now when you request `/admin/home/fakefolder/index` the `Index` action of `HomeController` within the `Admin` are will be executed.

Comment: Maybe you have some other routes defined which are not compatible with this. Hard to say without seeing your actual route definitions. Because if you try this in a new project, add an Admin area and replace the default route definition with the one I showed in my answer it will work exactly as expected. Which is leading me to believe that there must be something else in your code.

Comment: You are right, I'm a stupid .. I added it in the App_Start/RouteConfig.cs .. the correct position is of course in the AreaRegistration.cs .. I lost one hour for this stupid error :S .. anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `MapRoute` that expects an extra parameter in your route (fakefolder in the example below). Then, the routing occurs as usual, where the controller's action serves the page. Example:

```
routes.MapRoute(
          name: "FakeFolder",
          url: "{controller}/{fakefolder}/{action}",
          defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "index", fakefolder = UrlParameter.Optional}
      );
```

Notice that with this routing you can use any "folder name" since it is just a placeholder.

Url example:
`myController/SomeFakeFolder/someAction` will execute the action `someAction` in `myController`